# /etc/hosts file not redirecting

Tags: network, dns

*There are several questions about this, but none seem to address what I'm seeing.*

After editing my /etc/hosts with vi with a test redirect, nothing is redirecting when I visit in a browser, including Safari, Chrome and Firefox. This is on MacOs Sierra.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1   www.cnn.com/
```

the result of `$ cat /private/etc/hosts` shows the same contents.

I have tried flushing the cache two ways:

```
$ sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
$ dscacheutil -flushcache
```

I have also rebooted my machine.

How can I get my /etc/hosts file to redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely picky about the format of the /etc/hosts file. You have a "/" after the domain name, and this will confuse it (actually, it'll think that's part of the host name, and since you're trying to connect to the host "www.cnn.com" *not* "www.cnn.com/", it just doesn't match). So just remove the "/" and you should be good. There's no need to reset any caches.

Comment: Welp, that worked. What about sites that don't have www? For example, "127.0.0.1    imgur.com" as an entry isn't redirecting, even without the trailing forward slash.

Comment: @steel That looks like it should work. There might be some invisible characters causing trouble, though; try printing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet /etc/hosts`. That'll show tabs as "^I" and newlines as "$"; if you see anything else in there, that's probably the problem.

Comment: The reason `imgur.com` doesn't work in your hosts file is that it isn't a complete host name, it's a domain name. You must have the entire fully qualified domain name in hosts. When you type `imgur.com` into your browser the domain tells the browser to redirect to `www.imgur.com` - the FQDN.

Comment: @TonyWilliams A host name is just a domain name with a computer ("host") associated with it. imgur.com has an address (A) record in DNS, and there's a computer at that address, so it's a hostname; even if it didn't, adding it to /etc/hosts would make it function as a hostname. Also, www.imgur.com redirects to plain imgur.com.